# Where do I put FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE for Android 12 head?

Tags: android, xamarin, uno-platform

When I update my Xamarin Android head to compile using Android 12, and change the minimal version to 10.0 and the target to 12.0, I get the following exception when the application starts:

`Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: '[Package Name]: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.`

The stacktrace is

```
at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:196)
at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:128)
at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:93)
at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

Now my project contains no such `PendingIntent` so I am wondering what I should do.

Comment: Where is this pending intent being created in the stack?

Comment: No idea, its an Uno-Platform project. So I guess its being done in its internals. There is very little platform specific code

Comment: So I would suggest you report an issue on the Uno repository. They would need to fix this issue. Unless it is fired in a method that can be overridden then you can't do much about it.

Comment: We don't seem to use `PendingIntent` anywhere in our repository directly, but it might be some dependency. Can you try updating all packages you reference to latest version? Especially AndroidX and Google Play ones (if any) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68228666/targeting-s-version-10000-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag-immutable-or-fl . Also - does this happen for you with a blank Uno app as well?

Comment: @MartinZikmun I just tried, and it doesn't happen with a blank app. I will go through the dependencies.

Comment: Either way the stack trace for your exception will reveal what is causing it.

Comment: @Cheesebaron There is no stacktrace. It just shows `[External Code]`

Comment: There is always a stack trace. Just keep pressing continue and check the debug output.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Ah, it showed up in the output panel (duh...)

Comment: So are you using some plugin like Shiny or something like that to do background work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240955/discussion-between-patrick-decoster-and-cheesebaron).

Answer (score 1):

In this case adding the `Xamarin.AndroidX.Work.Runtime` NuGet package did the trick. In general this exception could mean a dependent package is not updated to support this Android 12 requirement.

Comment: Do i need to init this package? I tried this, adding this to my xamarin.androi project, but it didnt work.

Comment: I guess we'll never know