# Xamarin Forms error in background push notifications

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I use firebase to push notifications in Xamarin forms, works fine when application open but when test in background I got exaptation
**Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.**

I Searched for this error and find ,should install **Xamarin.AndroidX.Work.Runtime** Nuget package, install **Xamarin.AndroidX.Work.Work.Runtime.Ktx** Nuget package and install **Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics** , I installed them but not work the same exception still appear. how can I fix this exaptation?

this log data

> [AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-PNFirebaseMessagingService
> [AndroidRuntime] Process: com.raitotec.manaawateer, PID: 2365
> [AndroidRuntime] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> com.raitotec.manaawateer: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires
> that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating
> a PendingIntent. [AndroidRuntime] Strongly consider using
> FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on
> the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with
> inline replies or bubbles. [AndroidRuntime]   at
> android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:378)
> [AndroidRuntime]  at
> android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:461)
> [AndroidRuntime]  at
> android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:447)
> [AndroidRuntime]  at
> android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:411)
> [AndroidRuntime]  at com.google.firebase.messaging.zza.zzh(Unknown
> Source:124) [AndroidRuntime]  at
> com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown
> Source:57) [AndroidRuntime]   at
> com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source:2) [AndroidRuntime]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
> [AndroidRuntime]  at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
> [AndroidRuntime]  at
> com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown
> Source:6) [AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

Comment: Did this answer help you?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73502543/app-crashes-targeting-s-version-31-and-above-requires-that-one-of-flag-immu#:~:text=Make%20sure%20you%20are%20on%20the%20latest%20version%20of%20the%20Google%20Analytics%20dependency.%20It%20apparently%20is%20setting%20up%20that%20PendingIntent%2C%20and%20only%20the%20developers%20of%20Google%20Analytics%20can%20change%20that%20behavior

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a new version of your notification plugin package and if so, update your app. In my case, I was using [a plugin](https://github.com/edsnider/localnotificationsplugin) that has not been updated for a long time and started crashing my app when I targeted Android 12. So I changed to a [newer plugin](https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification).